# Why does having a static nested class cause a second constructor to be added when it's not in the source?

Tags: java, design-patterns, singleton

I was trying to break BillPaugh Singleton solution using reflection, well I am able to do it but I can see two constructors while accessing the BillPaughSingleTon solution. Why so ? Also by trial and error found that the line inside HelperClass is causing this. Again why so ?

BillPaughClass

```
package creational.BillPaugh;

public class SingleTonBillPaugh
{
  private SingleTonBillPaugh instance;

  public static SingleTonBillPaugh getInstance()
  {
    return SingleTonHelper.instance;
  }

  private SingleTonBillPaugh()
  {
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " instance is going to be created");
  }

  static class SingleTonHelper
  {
    private static final SingleTonBillPaugh instance = new SingleTonBillPaugh(); //if we remove this line, multiple constructor will not be there. But this line is needed for singleton. 
  }
}
```

Breaking SingleTon using Reflection .

```
package creational.BillPaugh;

import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;

public class BreakBillPaughUsingReflection
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {

    SingleTonBillPaugh singletonInstance1 = SingleTonBillPaugh.getInstance();
    System.out.println("singletonInstance1 " + singletonInstance1);

    SingleTonBillPaugh singletonInstance2;
    Constructor[] constructors = SingleTonBillPaugh.class.getDeclaredConstructors();

    for (Constructor construct : constructors)
    {
      construct.setAccessible(true);
      try
      {
        singletonInstance2 = (SingleTonBillPaugh) construct.newInstance();
        System.out.println("singletonInstance2 " + singletonInstance2);
      }
      catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException
        | InvocationTargetException e)
      {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }// end for

    Constructor[] constructors2 = NormalClass.class.getDeclaredConstructors();

  }
}
```

Proof of two constructor.

[image]

Comment: You are 90% correct. But only having only static inner class does not cause this addition. There have to have a line of creating one outer class instance inside that inner class. - ya I should have asked in that way having few lines of code, this may turned away people from this question. :(

Comment: You probably want to remove the `private SingleTonBillPaugh instance;` declaration from the outer class as you're not using it (and it's an instance variable, where it probably should have been `static` if being used).

Comment: Sure T. J. Crowder thanks, private SingleTonBillPaugh instance; can be removed. But even after removing does not solve the problem. It still shows 2 constructors. just tried.

Comment: is this related to java synthetic class ? one of my friend just pinged me this in lynch. http://www.javaworld.com/article/2073578/java-s-synthetic-methods.html

Comment: @anirban - Yes. It is related to *Synthetic methods*. Adding  `System.out.println(constructors[0].isSynthetic());
  System.out.println(constructors[1].isSynthetic());` will give you `false` and `true`.

Comment: Your image is misleading (which makes me wonder about your IDE). It's showing the second constructor as taking a `SingleTonBillPaugh` instance, but when I try this, it's taking a `SingleTonBillPaugh$1` instance -- a very different thing.

Comment: Thanks. I am using java SE 1.7 with Eclipse juno + win 8.1 64bit  don't know if this matters. At least java version may matter in above debug information disparity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's my take:

Because the `SingleTonBillPaugh` constructor in the source is `private`, `SingleTonBillPaugh$SingleTonHelper` can't access it, so the compiler generates a synthetic constructor `SingleTonBillPaugh$SingleTonHelper` *can* access. This is what synthetic methods and constructors are for: To provide a means of accessing the containing class's private data.

The bigger question to my mind is why does the synthetic constructor accept an argument, and why is the type of the argument `SingleTonBillPaugh$1`? (Your screenshot makes it look like it's a `SingleTonBillPaugh` instance, but in my tests it's actually a `SingleTonBillPaugh$1` instance — that is, there's a third class being generated here in addition to `SingleTonBillPaugh` and `SingleTonBillPaugh$SingleTonHelper`).

My answer to *that* question is: Because otherwise, there would be two constructors differentiated only by the fact that one is synthetic and accessible by `SingleTonBillPaugh$SingleTonHelper` and the other isn't. Java requires that signatures be more different than that, so it generates a class for the sole reason of differentiating the synthetic constructor from the non-synthetic one.

We can see that we do indeed have a `SingleTonBillPaugh$1` class, and if we `javap -p -c SingleTonBillPaugh\$1` it, we get:

```
class SingleTonBillPaugh$1 {
}
```

Doesn't get a lot more minimal than that, which suggests it is indeed purely to act as an argument type for the synthetic constructor. We can further confirm that by looking at the bytecode for `SingleTonBillPaugh$SingleTonHelper` using `javap -p -c SingleTonBillPaugh\$SingleTonHelper`:

```
class SingleTonBillPaugh$SingleTonHelper {
  private static final SingleTonBillPaugh instance;

  SingleTonBillPaugh$SingleTonHelper();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #2                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  static SingleTonBillPaugh access$000();
    Code:
       0: getstatic     #1                  // Field instance:LSingleTonBillPaugh;
       3: areturn

  static {};
    Code:
       0: new           #3                  // class SingleTonBillPaugh
       3: dup
       4: aconst_null
       5: invokespecial #4                  // Method SingleTonBillPaugh."<init>":(LSingleTonBillPaugh$1;)V
       8: putstatic     #1                  // Field instance:LSingleTonBillPaugh;
      11: return
}
```

Note how (right near the end) it's calling the one-argument version of the constructor (passing in `null`).

And in fact, it seems to always do this — add one new argument to the end of the constructor's argument list. If I change the private constructor to accept a `String` and update `SingleTonHelper` to pass it `""`, the synthetic constructor ends up being `SingleTonBillPaugh(String, SingleTonBillPaugh$1)`.

---

Re your question below:

> I kept one sysout in no argument constructor and when inner class called no argument constructor of outer class (which supposedly be synthetic constructor) the same sysout is printed. Why so? is it because internally synthetic constructor calls my provided pvt constructor?

Exactly, the synthetic constructor calls the private one. Times like this, it's nice to dip into the bytecode:

Here's my copy of `SingleTonBillPaugh.java`:

```
public class SingleTonBillPaugh
{
    public static SingleTonBillPaugh getInstance()
    {
        return SingleTonHelper.instance;
    }

    private SingleTonBillPaugh()
    {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " instance is going to be created");
    }

    static class SingleTonHelper
    {
        private static final SingleTonBillPaugh instance = new SingleTonBillPaugh();
    }
}
```

If we compile that, then use `javap -p -c SingleTonBillPaugh`, we get:

```
public class SingleTonBillPaugh {
  public static SingleTonBillPaugh getInstance();
    Code:
       0: invokestatic  #2                  // Method SingleTonBillPaugh$SingleTonHelper.access$000:()LSingleTonBillPaugh;
       3: areturn

  private SingleTonBillPaugh();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #3                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: getstatic     #4                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
       7: new           #5                  // class java/lang/StringBuilder
      10: dup
      11: invokespecial #6                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder."<init>":()V
      14: invokestatic  #7                  // Method java/lang/Thread.currentThread:()Ljava/lang/Thread;
      17: invokevirtual #8                  // Method java/lang/Thread.getName:()Ljava/lang/String;
      20: invokevirtual #9                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
      23: ldc           #10                 // String  instance is going to be created
      25: invokevirtual #9                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
      28: invokevirtual #11                 // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
      31: invokevirtual #12                 // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
      34: return

  SingleTonBillPaugh(SingleTonBillPaugh$1);
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method "<init>":()V
       4: return
}
```

As we can see, the `SingleTonBillPaugh(SingleTonBillPaugh$1)` constructor, written in source code form, woudl basically be:

```
SingleTonBillPaugh(SingleTonBillPaugh$1 unused) {
    this();
}
```

Comment: Agreed vote up, cloud clearing statement. just one confusion I kept one sysout in no argument constructor and when inner class called no argument constructor of outer class (which supposedly be synthetic constructor) the same sysout is printed. Why so? is it because internally synthetic constructor calls my provided pvt constructor? else sysout would not be there.

Comment: @anirban: Exactly, the synthetic calls the private constructor. I've added to the answer to confirm it, but that's exactly right.

Comment: Thanks for your effort.